# How to automate OOBE System Configuration, install Apps, add drivers, GPO and network Configuration on brand new computers with Windows 11?

Tags: windows-11, automation, mdt, mds

**tl;dr;** We need to automate the Windows 11: configuration of a couple of hundred **Brand New Computers** that come with **Windows 11 Pro x64 pre-installed**. Is it possible to use MDS/MDT for this o is there something better to accomplish these goals?

---

Where I work we need to automate the configuration of a couple of hundred brand new computers with Windows 11 pro x64. Once the PCs are delivered, we were given a limited amount of time to finish the config of all of them. **We want to keep the factory default image** and just automate the process that happens after you power on the computer for the first time.

**Example:**
[image]

I´ve searched around and found that MDS/MDT could be an option; I´ve setup a windows server 2019 VM and started making experiments with it; but we don't want to re-image the PCs, we just want to automate the following steps:

- Config the OOBE System (user, keyboard, language, network, etc.),
- Install a bunch of open-source apps that can be installed in silent mode (libre office, 7-zip, sumatraPDF, etc.)
- Inject drivers for all our  printers.
- Some GPO configurations and network configurations.

**Is it possible to use MDS/MDT for this or is there something better to accomplish these goals? Is it possible to use MDT's Post OS Installation Sequence to achieve this?**

Any advice or pointing in the right direction is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Are these domain joined machines or will they be domain joined eventually?

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle we don´t want them to join a domain; although it´s possible we might need to have them join one very down the line.

Comment: All answers you seek for starting points are here: https://www.reddit.com/r/MDT/comments/12lwaum/using_mdt_to_only_run_post_installation_sequences/, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/automate-oobe, and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/automate-windows-setup?view=windows-11. Basically, "business" and "retail OEM" based Windows OOBE are not the same. You should be using business solutions for business systems for simplification, streamlining, & standardizing post OOBE configurations. Doing it otherwise is probably possible.